# SQL query for calculating a total column value with different conditions in it

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a query built at the moment that gives me the SUM of a column under certain conditions but I'm looking to expand it and can't work out at all.

My current query is this.

```
   select COUNT (STTL_AMOUNT) as "COUNT",
   SUM   (STTL_AMOUNT) as "Settlement Amount",
   HOST_DATE as "Settlement Date"
   FROM  OPR_OPERATION
   WHERE    MCC = '6011'
   AND      MSG_TYPE ='MSGTPRES'
   AND      HOST_DATE >= TRUNC( SYSDATE )
   GROUP BY HOST_DATE;
```

However, in the row,  I also have another column called 'returned'. The values for 'returned' are '0' or '-1' and I want the same conditions to be used as above but if the returned column has a '-1', I'd like to subtract the value of (STTL_AMOUNT) for that row from the total SUM of (SETTL_AMOUNT).
So I would need something similar to SUM (STTL_AMOUNT) where returned = '0' - SUM (SETTL_AMOUNT) where returned = '1' but that doesnt work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what you asked for.
You want to add or subtract based on the value of a column.
You can use a case in the SUM:

```
   SELECT COUNT (STTL_AMOUNT) as "COUNT",
   SUM(CASE WHEN returned=0 THEN STTL_AMOUNT ELSE(STTL_AMOUNT * -1) End ) as "Settlement Amount",
   HOST_DATE as "Settlement Date"
   FROM  OPR_OPERATION
   WHERE    MCC = '6011'
   AND      MSG_TYPE ='MSGTPRES'
   AND      HOST_DATE >= TRUNC( SYSDATE )
   GROUP BY HOST_DATE;
```

Running a test with the values that you provided in the comments i get the result that I expect, 25307. It's 47807 - 22500.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_case_tb] (
[Returned ] BIT NOT NULL,
[STTL_AMOUNT]   INT         NOT NULL
    
);

INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(0,2500)
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(0, 1307) 
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(0, 500) 
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(1, 500)
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(0, 2500) 
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(0, 2500) 
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(1, 2500) 
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(0, 4500)
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(0, 4500)
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(1, 4500)
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(0, 5000)
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(0, 5000)
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(1, 5000)
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(0, 4500)
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(0, 5000)
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(1, 5000)
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(0, 5000)
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(1, 5000)
INSERT INTO test_case_tb values(0, 5000)
 
 select * from test_case_tb
 
 SELECT COUNT (STTL_AMOUNT) as "COUNT",
 SUM(CASE WHEN Returned=0 THEN STTL_AMOUNT ELSE(STTL_AMOUNT * -1) End ) as "Settlement Amount"
 FROM  test_case_tb  
 
 SELECT SUM(STTL_AMOUNT) as sum_returned_1
 FROM  test_case_tb 
 where Returned = 1 
 
 SELECT SUM(STTL_AMOUNT) as sum_returned_0
 FROM  test_case_tb 
 where Returned = 0
```

Comment: Actually, after checking the figures, this query is not quite correct. SELECT COUNT (STTL_AMOUNT) as "COUNT",
   SUM(CASE WHEN Returned =0 THEN STTL_AMOUNT ELSE(STTL_AMOUNT * -1) End ) as "Settlement Amount",
   HOST_DATE as "Settlement Date"
   FROM  OPR_OPERATION
   WHERE    MCC = '6011'
   AND      MSG_TYPE ='MSGTPRES'
   AND      HOST_DATE >= TRUNC( SYSDATE -1 )
   GROUP BY HOST_DATE;   as it is giving me the wrong value.

Comment: I have altered is slightly to (STTL_AMOUNT) as "COUNT",
   SUM(CASE WHEN Returned =1 THEN STTL_AMOUNT ELSE(STTL_AMOUNT * -0) End ) as "Settlement Amount",
   HOST_DATE as "Settlement Date"
   FROM  OPR_OPERATION
   WHERE    MCC = '6011'
   AND      MSG_TYPE ='MSGTPRES'
   AND      HOST_DATE >= TRUNC( SYSDATE -1 ) and that gives me the total STTL_AMOUNT as the total of Returned =1 but I need my total STTL_AMOUNT to be where RETURNED =0 - RETURNED =1

Comment: Or - the total of STTL_AMOUNT minus any record that has column 'Returned' = 1

Comment: RETURNED STTL_AMOUNT
0                 2500
0                 1307
0                 500
1                 500
0                 2500
0                 2500
1                 2500
0                 4500
0                 4500
1                 4500
0                 5000
0                 5000
1                 5000
0                 4500
0                 5000
1                 5000
0                 5000
1                 5000
0                 5000
So in this example I have 19 rows and I need to know the total STTL_AMOUNT when all rows that have RETURNED = 1 are deducted

Comment: I just ran a test with the values that you sent and it returns what i expect 25307. It's 47807 - 22500. Is this the result that you expect? I removed all the filters and kept only STTL_AMOUNT and returned. Maybe there is something in the where clause that you need to alter?

Comment: Ah no sorry - 47807 is the total that I need. The total of all 19 records = 70307. But then I need to deduct the value of the rows that have Returned =1. The totals of the rows that have returned =1 comes to 22500. So it would be 70307 minus 22500 = 47807 if that makes sense?

Comment: Ok, i got it now. In that case you can do this : `SUM(STTL_AMOUNT) - SUM(CASE WHEN Returned=1 THEN STTL_AMOUNT ELSE 0 End ) as "Settlement Amount"`

Comment: That is all the records with returned = 0 , so you could do this as well : `SUM(CASE WHEN Returned=0 THEN STTL_AMOUNT ELSE 0 End ) as "Settlement Amount"`